# Integration Account Project on Visual Studio 2015 - Add generated item tab for create schemas from endpoint, wsdl, etc

Tags: visual-studio-2015, xsd, biztalk, azure-logic-apps, biztalk-schemas

Using VisualStudio 2015 on a BizTalk server Environment, I have some templates for generating xsd schemas, starting from various sources, like endpoint of active services, wsdl files, etc.
Now I'm trying to made the same in visual studio 2015 with an integration account project (for logic apps), but I don't find the templates.

I attached a screen of a BizTalk project with open the "Add generated item" tab:

[image: "Add generated item" tab]

Answer (score 0):

Install everything from the BizTalk adapter installation, you're probably missing the complete WCF LOB Adapter SDK.

After installation you might sill miss the option, you then have to open the tab again. (Yes annoying bug).

Answer (score 0):

But in my case I don't have full BizTalk installed. I have the "Microsoft Azure Logic Apps Enterprise Integration Tools for Visual Studio 2015 2.0" extension of Visual Studio 2015. I don't found the WCF LOB Adapter SDK for the integration account.